# How to save an object after exit

Tags: vb.net, winforms, class, object, save

So I'm currently working with VB.net and winforms and I need the have objects created from my classes saved so they are still there if I exit the program and open it again.

I also needed to make them dynamically so I was going to add them to a dictionary on creation and save that dictionary in the settings, but it seems that you can't save a dictionary in settings.

So how can I do this? Maybe something like save the creations in an excel sheet and recreate them on load each time, that might work but seems a tad inefficient, Thanks in advance, Ed.
(p.s. sorry if this makes no sense it's 1:30am in the morning here and I'm not really with it.)

Comment: It depends on what the objects are

Comment: As in one I've made from a class.

Comment: You could look into serialization

Comment: aside from what kind of objects they are also what kind of object do you want them to save (it will refer also on how you will open them using your program)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So just putting this here in case anybody else has this problem, I took Plutonix's advice and looked into serialization and it sorted my problem, used this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oN_YHn3EVOs